# Update media library files after upload via FTP

Tags: media, ftp, library

I had to upload many files massive and directly to /wp-content/uploads/[year]/[month]/ but those files does not appears in Dashboard>Media>Library

Is there a way to update or refresh it to load those files or it's simply happening because it should have been writen also in database and I avoided it? In this case, is there a plugin to fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Avoid direct upload WordPress doesn't scan upload directory for new files, instead use WordPress media uploader to add files WordPress automatically creates folder and store them accordingly.

But you can use this plugin to import those uploaded files into WordPress, it should help you https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/

Comment: welcome :) mark as correct answer, it may helps people in future.

Comment: Uh, done, I though I was unable to do it since I have no reputation, however, thanks again! :)

Comment: Curious @McKernel, did this work for adding a large number of files? The plugin's description is a bit dubious in that regard. :P

Comment: This plugin may better serve this purpose today. https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-sync/